# Is an Azure VPN connection possible with a Billion 7800N

Tags: vpn, azure

Is an Azure VPN connection possible with a Billion 7800N?

I'm getting the feeling its not, but can't find any info on it, so would like a definite yes/no if anyone knows?

I've got a Azure Virtual Network set up as per the tutorial, and a gateway set. Now I'm trying to configure the PPTP Client on my Billion 7800N router. Major stumbling block seems to the the routers insistence on a username and password, where as Azure has a pre-shared key.

Background, I'm tying to connect my office to Auzre in order to access my VM's. I ideally want it 100% on in a site-to-site config.

I'm just a developer with a OK understanding on networking, so please forgive any misguided ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick search through the user manual for your router finds only references to PPTP VPNs. This type of VPN uses a username & password and is usually used for ad-hoc connections from users. (The user dials the VPN connection directly from their OS, similar to how modem connections used to work, then they have access to the VPN from just their machine).

A pre-share key is used with an IPSec VPN, which is usually the preferred method for a site-to-site VPN. However, it appears your Billion router doesn't do this. (I can't find 'ipsec' anywhere in the manual).

It may be possible to configure a PPTP VPN on Azure and connect to that from your Billion router, or you can change the router for something else.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

You're out of luck here.  [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156075.aspx) effectively suggests that you'll need a *real* router, not a SOHO one.

The good news is, that a second hand Cisco ASA 5505, Cisco 1801, 2801, 2901 or maybe even a 2611 won't set you back the earth, and you should be able to configure ut.

Comment: Great suggestions on the 2nd hand routers, sorry, not enough rep yet to vote you up.

Comment: It's ok.  Lots of people tend to forget that for low-throughput routing, or non-production use, that older hardware is still a perfectly usable option. Source: I've got 3 flight cases full of old routers for labbing.